# How Achieve AWS MQTT topics in azure IoT and what is the work around for the similar functionality

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management, azure-iot-dps

I'm exploring Azure IoT and looking for implementation of MQTT topics (a functionality in AWS IoT) in Azure too. How to achieve this and if Azure doesn't support this, then how to achieve this via alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MQTT protocol to connect to Azure IoT Hub. IoT Hub enables devices to communicate with the IoT Hub device endpoints using:

- MQTT v3.1.1 on TCP port 8883
- MQTT v3.1.1 over WebSocket on TCP port 443.

The connection to IoT Hub using MQTT can be established by using [Azure IoT SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-sdks) or using the MQTT protocol directly. Refer to the article [TLS/SSL configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub#tlsssl-configuration) which provides a sample code in Python demonstrating usage of the protocol directly.

Note that support for MQTT 5 with Azure IoT Hub is still in preview state and offers limited feature support. Here are the resources that will provide more information on MQTT support

- [Communicate with an IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-connect-to-iot-hub)
- [IoT Hub MQTT 5 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot/iot-mqtt-5-preview)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is about custom hierarchical topics (incl. wildcard support).

To achieve this in Azure use the EventGrid MQTT broker.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-overview